# setText() in afterTextChanged() shows the text in reverse order

Tags: android, android-edittext

My code:

```
    fractionNumEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        boolean ignoreChange = false;

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!ignoreChange) {
                String string = String.valueOf(s);
                if (string.length() > 2) {
                    string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
                    ignoreChange = true;
                    fractionNumEt.setText(string);
                    ignoreChange = false;
                }
            }

        }
```

....

I am trying to limit the characters to length 2, but want to keep listening. When I type '1','2',  it displays "12" which is fine. Now when I type '3', it writes "31" instead of "23". 
What on earth is going on!
I also tried:

```
string = string.substring(1, string.length());
```

in this case it works for the first time only n then nothing is changed.

Comment: Why you are using 
 String string = String.valueOf(s);

Comment: ignore that, i was just fighting with every possibility

Comment: you can use String string = s.toString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because after `setText()`, EditText's cursor returns to first position. Then, any new number will be added at the begging of the String.

Try to update your code as follows:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(!ignoreChange) {
        String string = String.valueOf(s);
        if (string.length() > 2) {
            string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
            ignoreChange = true;
            fractionNumEt.setText(string);
            fractionNumEt.setSelection(fractionNumEt.getText().length());
            ignoreChange = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Just a suggestion**

Check Editable Docs [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html)

I think you don't need to convert it to String. `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` receives a Editable as argument. You can change it directly. Don't need to covert it to a String.

Moreover: You don't even need to make EditText.setText() because any change in the editable, will be passed automatically to EditText (since `afterTextChanged` is called by android and give you a chance to update the text few moments before to effectively display that text in the EditText).

Maybe, something like that:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(!ignoreChange) {
        if(s.length() > 2) {
            s.delete(s.length() - 1,s.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Play a little bit with Editable and you will see that it is easier.

Comment: @usman I update my answer with a suggestion. I think you don't need to convert to a String and you don't need to use EditText.setText()... Just modify the Editable that you receives...